# Display selected value from dataGridView to display in Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm currently working on a c# project, my problem is that i can't seem to figure out a way to get a selected row from the dataGridView to be written to the database. In simple terms i want the user to click a certain field from the dataGridView and that specific value should be written to the database. I am using microsoft access as the database and visual studio (C#) to write the code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please, read carefully the [guide](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question and increase the chances for it to  get answered.

Comment: You want to write back to the source table or to another table? Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101617/how-to-reference-a-datagridviewcell-by-column-name-in-a-datagridviewrow

Comment: I want to write it to another table